# Binary crossentropy doesn't work in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, classification

im trying to train a neural network with sensorvalues to predict where an error occurs. The input is are 6048 values (80% for training).The inputshape is 6400x1. I normaliszed these input values, so that 0 values are -1 and all other sensorvalues are between 0 and 1. My labels have the shape of 6048x1 and only one value is 1 (where the error is in the simulation) and all other values are 0. In reality it is a 2d problem but i flatten both the input and output. I used the following network:

```
model1 = tf.keras.Sequential()

    model1 = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(6400,)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(78*78,activation="softmax"),

    ])
    model1.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy')
    
    model1.fit(x_tra,y_tra,epochs = 3)
```

In training the loss doesn't change at all and stays at 0.0016.
Then i predicted some training values with network, but these are all extremely small (like 1e-5) but the max is although only 0.000917.

I tried changing the loss function and also the activation function from the last layer to sigmoid but it did not change much. I expected  to have  outputs with values between 0 and 1, but much higher so near the real error position values like 0.8-1 and everywhere else values under 0.5. Is it a problem, that i have flattend the input and output?

Im quite new to tensorflow and would appreciate your help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To use, `binary_crossentropy` as loss function, the last Dense layer should have 1 neuron and  be defined as `tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation="sigmoid")`.

If the neurons in last dense layer is greater than or equal to 2 (neuron_count >=2), you should define the layer as given below and then use `categorical_crossentropy` as loss function.

```
neuron_count =2
model1.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(neuron_count,activation="softmax"))
model1.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy')
```

In the last Dense layer of your model, number of neurons is 78*78. For it to converge use `categorical_crossentropy`. Else change your neuron count to 1 and use `sigmoid` as activation function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried categrorical_crossentropy, but the loss in training just stays at 8.7. And the maximum value in prediction is also only 0.000187 again.